# How can i load div on Page Load based on ID value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `JQuery` `SlideUp` and `slideDown` methods to `show/hide` panels. How can load or display the first record Contact information as a default?

Right now it loads blank because i set the panel `display:none`:
`<div class="panel rpspanel panel-default" id="@item.ID" style="display: none">` otherwise it loads all if i have multiple results.

Need help to load the first one when the page loads. And the rest on click event which working perfect.

**Left Panel:**

Pass the item id (or any unique value) to the `li` in `data-id` attribute

```
<ul id="treeview">
     @foreach (var item in rpInfo)
        {
          <li data-expanded="true" class="panel-handler" data-id="@item.id">
              <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>@item.PartyName
                <ul>
                     <li data-expanded="true">  <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> @item.ContactName </li>
                 </ul>
           </li>
         }
  </ul>
```

**Right Panel:**

`id attribute` to all panels. the **same `id` which i have passed in the left panel.**

```
  @foreach (var item in rpInfo)
            {                    
                var DeleteModal = "#myModal" + item.ID;                   
                var mid = "myModal" + item.ID;
                <div class="panel rpspanel panel-default" id="@item.ID" style="display: none">
                              Contact Information</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                              <div class="card card-understated">
                                  <div class="card-heading">
                                      <h4>@(Localizer["Contact Preview "])</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                      <p>
                                          @item.ContactName<br>
                                          @item.ContactTitle<br>
                                          @item.PartyName<br>
                                          @item.AddressLine1<br />
                                          @item.City, @item.State @item.Country
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>                          
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  }
```

**Jquery script:**

On on left panel on `li click` get the `data-id` attribute value.
Hide all panels .
Show the panel with the specified id attribute.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".panel-handler").click(function() {
            let id = $(this).data("id");
            $(".rpspanel").slideUp();
            $("#" +id).slideDown();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate `function` for the `slideDown()` functionality based on `id`, and pass `id` of the first `.panel-handler` on load of document:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".panel-handler").click(function() {
        showInfo($(this).data("id"));        
    });

    function showInfo(id){
        $(".rpspanel").slideUp();
        $("#" +id).slideDown();
    }

    // For first time
    showInfo($(".panel-handler").eq(0).data("id"))
});
```